# How to open aspx form inside an iFrame

Tags: asp.net, iframe, webforms

I need to open an aspx form inside an iframe so i need a direct link to use in

But the problem is, the form that im trying to open in an iframe is on a aspx page and when i enter that url of that page in my iframe i get the full page inside iframe yet i need only the form.

now my question is how can i get specific url for the form only through the source code <==

is that possible anyway to import only one specific part of a page into an iframe?

thanx in advance

Comment: Are the aspx page and the page with the iframe on the same domain?

Comment: no they r not. the only thing i have from that aspx website is the source code that im opening on my browser. i need to know is it possible to bring the form inside the iframe yet we dont have access to the aspx files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the page with the form is from another Web site that you don't control, there is nothing you can do. The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) forbids you to interact with the page in the iframe.

There are techniques that allow you to work around the same origin policy (CORS, postMessage), but all require some level of access enabled on the target page.

Comment: thank you Christophe. I agree with u. its not possible without any access

Answer (score 0):

Turn your form into a UserControl (if it's not already) and drop it on to a new, blank page that has no header/footer/navigation, then load this new page's URL into your iframe.

Comment: thank you Netricity. but i dont have access to aspx file. Actually the form im trying to access inside the iframe is on an external website that does a search on their database and shows a result. i used to get a direct link to the form and show it in an iframe on my website but now i wont get a direct link to the form due to some design changes in that website. i was trying to find a way to show the form only in an iframe but it sounds kinda impossible through the source code only i think...